# Return type in recursion

Tags: c

I  am confuse about the behavior of the following function. Below are some programs on which i stuck:

Case 1:

```
void f()
{
    printf("wow\t");
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the output as expected `wow`.

Case 2:

```
void f()
{
    printf("wow\t");
}

int main()
{
    f(f());
    return 0;
}
```

It gives `error: invalid use of void expression` which is obvious.

Case 3:

```
int f()
{
    printf("wow\t");
}

int main()
{
    f(f());
    return 0;
}
```

Why it give the output `wow     wow`?

`f()` has return type `int`. But in `main` it is not stored in any variable. Also `f()` has not taken any argument but in case 3 it will take argument returned by `f()`.

The same code doesn't work in C++.

Comment: do you understand code yourself?

Comment: Where is the recursion? The recursion is playing hide-and-seek ...

Comment: In C you have to explicitly tell the compiler if a function should take no arguments, i.e. declare the function as `void f(void)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `f(f());` calls `f` from the inner function call and then calls `f` from the outer function call. That you don't store the return value from `f` doesn't do anything. The compiler can't avoid calling a function just because you ignore its return value unless it knows the function has no consequences, and this function does have consequences.

It's not unusual at all to ignore the return value of a function. For example, you might have a "remove entries" function that returns the number of entries it removed. You might call that function in a context where you don't care how many entries it returned, so you ignore the return value. The function still has to run or the entry wouldn't get removed. Heck, you're ignoring the return value of `printf`. You'd be quite surprised if it didn't get called though.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you have to explicitly declare the fact that a function does not receive any parameters. For example:

```
int f(void)
{
    printf("wow\t");
}

int main()
{
    f(f());
    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
error: too many arguments to function ‘f’
```

In C++ it's different. `int f() {}` is equivalent to `int f(void) {}`.